# Filter rows based on condition

Tags: r, dataframe

below is the dataframe df. Can we filter it based on conditions. Like, if there are charaters in 3rd col and Null in 3rd col, those should be filtered

```
  row col value
1   1   0    ID
2   1   1    12
3   1   2    12
4   1   3     4
5   1   4
```

Expected output

```
  row col value
2   1   1    12
3   1   2    12
4   1   3     4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use :

```
subset(df, !(grepl("[A-Za-z]",value) | value == ''))

#  row col value
#2   1   1    12
#3   1   2    12
#4   1   3     4
```

This removes rows where characters (`[A-Za-z]`) OR empty values are present.

Answer (score 4):

We can perhaps just keep all the rows with digits in `value` column:

```
df[grepl('\\d', df$value),]
```

Output:

```
  row col value
2   1   1    12
3   1   2    12
4   1   3     4
```

Answer (score 0):

It is also easier to convert to `numeric` and `subset` on the non NA elements

```
subset(df, !is.na(as.numeric(value)))
```

---

Or with `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
   filter(str_detect(value, "^[0-9.]+$"))
```